# How does OpenMP's omp_set_num_threads() work with 2 simultaneous OMP operations

Tags: visual-studio-2017, openmp

How does OpenMP's `omp_set_num_threads()` function affect two simultaneous OpenMP operations?  Is the number of threads cumulative or a hard limit?

For example, suppose two worker threads hit the following block of code at exactly the same time

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel for shared(n)  
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    // ... some complicated, parallelizable math here...
}
```

Will each operation get its own 4 threads (8 total) or will a total of 4 threads be divided among the two simultaneous operations?

(I assume the behavior, whatever it is, would be identical if I were to use the  OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable or the `num_threads` clause.  If I have that wrong, please tell me...)

I ask because I have a client using my SDK on a machine with a whole lotta cores.  He needs to make many calls to one of my SDK functions that is implemented with OpenMP. (I did not write it.  I inherited it). He wanted to experiment with parallelizing his calls to this function in search of faster overall throughput.  And he already has the ability to control the argument my code uses for `omp_set_num_threads()`.

I've realized I am not knowledgeable enough to advise him about what thread number value to use or even if parallelization (on top of OpenMP implementation) is a worthwhile avenue to explore.  So I'd at least like to understand what OpenMP is supposed to do in this case before I start my own tests.

If it matters I am using Visual Studio's 2017's Open MP so I guess just the 2.0 implementation

Comment: You should look up nested parallelism. Typically, this is not advised because it can lead to oversubscribing of cores and bad performance - but I understand your use-case may depend on it. However, I can't comment on the Microsoft's implementation of the ancient version of the standard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  To clarify, is this use case truly considered  "nested"?  Two threads are hitting the same OpenMP block at the same time.  But the OpenMP block is not invoking a second OpenMP block

Comment: My understanding of your example code is that two threads - coming from an outside OpenMP parallel region - each encounter the `omp parallel for` region you describe. Thus each thread tries to create a new team. That is nested parallelism in OpenMP.

Comment: You understand my example perfectly.  I just didn't understand that such a situation was considered nested parallelism by Open MP.   Seems almost like a misnomer to call that "nested" -- I typically think of one thing inside of another thing when I think of that word.   Until now, whenever I saw discussions of "nested" parallelism I was ignoring them, because that the writers were talking about something else.  Now I know better.  Thank you